# Breakpoints are crossed out, how can I make them valid?

Tags: java, eclipse, breakpoints, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

i got a tricky one:

[image: look At Breakpoints, they are crossed out!]

I can't set valid breakpoints. Not in Tests, neither in my Java Classes. I searched Stackoverflow and google, but I couldn't find anybody with the same problem.

I'm using STS(x86) and Maven.

**Edit:** It may seem confusing but I solved it by myself.
I have to go Run-> Skip all Breakpoints (it was set, and I wonder how it was set, because I didn't do it)

Comment: Had the same issue just now. Thanks! Seems like I accidentaly pressed CTRL+ALT+B at some point.

Comment: Which is @#£$%! annoying, since set/clear breakpoint is `CTRL`+`Shift`+`B` !

Answer (score 342, accepted):

There is a menu entry you have discovered for yourself that toggles the skipping of all breakpoints. There is also an icon for this in the "Breakpoints" View, and there may be a hot-key defined as well, all of which you may have triggered by accident.

Take a look at the **Run -> Skip All Breakpoints**.

Comment: I have to commit that I didn't use debugger since I switched to sts. I searched hotkeys and at skipping was no hotkey set. Like it was default setup from STS which I don't belive. What ever, I hope my post can help other users, if they got the same problem.

Comment: I had skipped all breakpoints one day in my efforts to clear all breakpoints, I had forgotten about this! Thanks for the eye opener!

Comment: I'd say 99% of visitors here are encountering what I encounter about once per year with Eclipse. There's apparently a bug in eclipse that causes this "Skip All Breakpoints" feature to turn ON all by itself even though you didn't actually turn it on.

Answer (score 29):

Screenshot of the 'skip all breakpoints' in eclipse.

[image]

When you click on 'skip all breakpoints'(which is selected), everything will become normal

Answer (score 9):

The shortcut key for placing a breakpoint in Eclipse (Ctrl + Shift + B) is quite similar to the one that skips all the breakpoint (Ctrl + Alt + B). Hence, if a "skip all breakpoints" condition is to be cancelled, it can be achieved by pressing "Ctrl + Alt + B" again.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! I must have hit this by accident. The Eclipse IDEs can be different but the shortcut works great!

Answer (score 4):

You should already be in debug perspective. If not just go to debug perspective. You should see disable all breakpoints button.  -

[image]

Click on it and it should allow all breakpoints.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) Run => Skip all breakpoints.
2) Run => remove all break points.

and then your debugger wont show cross sign and will keep debugging your app.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps below to fix this

1. select debug only tomcat server
2. debug particular application and then prompt came whether to re enable break points and I selected yes

Answer (score -1):

In mine case neither ctrl+alt+B is working nor I am getting any option in run->skip all breakpoint. Do we have any alternative options for fix this breakpoint issue

Comment: You're commenting and thus not contributing an answer. Comments should be in the comments section. You can also start a new question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35196085)